# javascript typescript create a object

Tags: javascript, angular, object, types

i have a property like this "data.property" = "16165456"..
i try to create a object like this

```
data {
   property : "16"
}
```

i use split and and loop but not work

```
    this.returnKey(model, this.to['pro1'], this.model[this.to['pro2']])
returnKey(model: any, name: string, value: string) {

        let nameParts = name.split("."),
            currentObject = model;
        for (let i in nameParts) {
            let part = nameParts[i]
            currentObject[part] = currentObject[part]

            this.currentObject = currentObject[part];
        }

        let part2 = nameParts[1];
        currentObject = value;
    }
```

Comment: There is no problem statement here. Please create a runnable snippet (using toolbar in editor) that runs this code with sample input, and illustrates the problem you experience. Provide what is expected, and what you get instead.

Comment: sorry man but i dont know what do you mean about runnable snippet ..the code not work because return data = '16'

Comment: do you help me man or tell me about the view of stack overflow ?

Comment: You can create a snippet by using the `<>` button in the question editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- `currentObject[part] = currentObject[part]` is a statement that accomplishes nothing. You'd want to indicate what to assign when that property does not yet exist, so do:

  ```
  currentObject[part] = currentObject[part] ?? {};
  ```
- `this.currentObject` is a property, and is not the variable with the same name. `this` is not appropriate here. Just assign to `currentObject`.
- The variable `part2` gets a value, but it is not used. So this doesn't accomplish anything.
- The final assignment `currentObject = value` will not affect the `model` object, only that local variable. So also this statement has no lasting effect.
- The `for` loop iterates one time too many. You'd need to stop one step earlier so you can still assign the `value` to the property of the parent object that needs to get it.

Here is a correction to all those issues:

```js
function returnKey(model, name, value) {
    let nameParts = name.split("."),
        key = nameParts.pop(), // extract the last property
        currentObject = model;
    for (let i in nameParts) { // Now we will iterate one time less
        let part = nameParts[i];
        // Initialise the property with `{}` when it is new:
        currentObject[part] = currentObject[part] ?? {};
        currentObject = currentObject[part];
    }
    // Assign to the deepest key, so the model will get it:
    currentObject[key] = value;
}

// Demo:
let name = "data.numeroApplication";
let value = "16165456";
let model = {};
returnKey(model, name, value);
console.log(model); // Model has mutated
```

Comment: or TS2538: Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.

75   currentObject[key] = value // error key

Comment: That is a typescript error. Just declare the type of `key` if in typescript. Can you debug and tell me what the value of `key` is? If it is `undefined` then what is the argument you have passed for `name`? Can you debug and tell me what the value is of `name` when you get this error?

Comment: if i declare  like key = '' ..i get a error.. i cant debug ..because i use an angular application ..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You should initialise `key` to get value from `nameParts.pop()`. Not `''`. Please add `console.log(name)` inside the function and tell me the value. I cannot reproduce your problem, so you are using some unexpected parameter value.

Comment: data.property is the value

Comment: OK, I cannot reproduce that (as you can see when running the snippet in my answer). Can you create a fiddle that I can run, which reproduces the issue?

Comment: i have modify your snippet whit the error

Comment: No, you just added a comment, which is what you said above. Instead, can you create a fiddle (not in my answer, but either in your question or on another site, like jsfiddle.com or some typescript fiddle site) -- which **reproduces** the issue (not a comment).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sow5v3np/1/ i have create this but i dont know ....how does it work?

Comment: That is not correct syntax. You cannot start a script with just part of a class. You need at least to type correct JavaScript.

Comment: i have solved the problem  key = nameParts.pop() ?? '', with nullish operator ..thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If that was necessary, then your `name` value was not like you said. In case of "data.property", `nameParts` is an array with 2 elements, and so `pop` cannot return `undefined`. But OK, good that you have solved it. I still would like to know what `name` is when you have that effect. There is no string that would split into an empty array with `split(".")`, or would produce an array element that is undefined. So please let me know which value of  `name` produces this `undefined` with `pop`.